# Stored procedures and PDO

Tags: stored-procedures, pdo

I'm trying to return row sets from a MySQL stored procedure call using PDO extension as my method.

```
function searchByExtension($extension_num) 
{

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("{CALL select_call(?)}");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $extension_num, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(!$rows){
        print 'Error!';
        die();
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        print $row[0].$row[1].$row[2].$row[4].$row[5].$row[6]."\n<br>";
    }

}
```

So a call to

```
$call_log->searchByExtension(2458412);
```

would loop through my data set printing the results to the browser accordingly, only it doesn't fly. The script reaches

```
print 'Error!';
```

and duly dies? The SP works fine from the shell.

Comment: What are these curly braces are for?

Comment: @YCS, thanks, it was the curly braces. These found their way in there from a tutorial somewhere online.

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
function searchByExtension($extension_num) 
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("CALL select_call(:input_extensionNum);");
    $stmt->bindParam(":input_extensionNum", $extension_num, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);

    //$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(!$rows){
        print 'Error!';
        die();
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        print $row[0].$row[1].$row[2].$row[4].$row[5].$row[6]."\n<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry Im new to this web site.